# JS use variable as id for document.getElementById Not working?

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm confused why this is ot working:

```
var blocks = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
        var i = 0;
        for(i=0;i<blocks.length;i++){
            var id = String(blocks[i].id);
            var col_pos_y = document.getElementById(id).style.top;
            alert(col_pos_y);

        }
```

Am I missing something, because firefox seems to just alert out a blank alert message? Anyone got an idea why this isn't working?

This is the html/php code for the generation of the td's

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="position: absolute; top: 80%; z-index:5;" border="0">
<?php
$blocks = array();
for($k=1;$k<=3;$k++){   
    $row_number = "row_".$k;
?>
    <tr id="<?php echo $row_number; ?>">
<?
    for($i=0;$i<=100;$i++){
        if($k==1){
            $rand_number = rand(0, 100);
        }
        else if($k==2){
            $rand_number = rand(30, 100);
        }
        else if($k==3){
            $rand_number = rand(50, 100);
        }
        if($rand_number<50){
            for($l=0;$l<=count($blocks);$l++){
                $row_counter = $k-1;
                if($blocks[$l]=="row_".$row_counter."_col_".$i."_type_grass"){
                    $block_exists="true";
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    $block_exists="false";
                }
            }
            if($block_exists=="true"){
                array_push($blocks, $row_number."_col_".$i."_type_grass");

                $background_position = generate_dirt_block();
                ?>
                    <td id="<?php echo $row_number; ?>_col_<?php echo $i ?>_type_grass" style="font-size: 10px; cursor: pointer; background-image:url('img/terrain.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: <?php echo $background_position ?>; min-width: 32px; height: 32px;">

                    </td>
                <?php
            }
            else{
                array_push($blocks, $row_number."_col_".$i."_type_blank");
                ?>
                     <td id="<?php echo $row_number; ?>_col_<?php echo $i ?>_type_blank" style="font-size: 10px; min-width: 32px; height: 32px;">

                     </td>
                <?php
            }
        }
        else if($rand_number>=50  && $rand_number<=100){
            array_push($blocks, $row_number."_col_".$i."_type_grass");
            for($l=0;$l<=count($blocks);$l++){
                $row_counter = $k-1;
                if($blocks[$l]=="row_".$row_counter."_col_".$i."_type_grass"){
                    $block_exists="true";
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    $block_exists="false";
                }
            }
            if($block_exists=="true"){
                $background_position = generate_dirt_block();
                ?>
                    <td id="<?php echo $row_number ?>_col_<?php echo $i ?>_type_grass" style="font-size: 10px; cursor: pointer; background-image:url('img/terrain.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: <?php echo $background_position ?>; min-width: 32px; height: 32px;">

                    </td>
                <?php
            }
            else{
                ?>
                    <td id="<?php echo $row_number; ?>_col_<?php echo $i ?>_type_grass" style="font-size: 10px; cursor: pointer; background-image:url('img/terrain.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0px -32px; min-width: 32px; height: 32px;">
                        <div style="width: 100%; position: relative; top: 0px;">
                            <div style="background-image:url('img/terrain.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: -384px 0px; width: 32px; height: 10px; position: absolute; top: -17px;">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }
?>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML associated with this? alos, why are you reforming the string after splitting it? It appears to be putting the string back together the same way it was before you called split().

Comment: Does "block_id" get a value? What does your TD ID look like?

Comment: yeh ignore that, that was me trying around it but `document.getElementById(blocks[i].id).style.top;` doesn't work either for some odd reason. I can't really post the whole html code because it's php which generates these td's which is like 100 lines of code, but I'll try

Comment: Just copy the rendered HTML - not the PHP that generates it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `getElementById()` wasn't working, then trying to access `.style.top` on the return value would error and the `alert` would never be reached.

The `.style.top` property of the element is simply blank (indicating that it has not been set with either JavaScript or the `style` attribute).

Use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) if you want to access the property as applied via the cascade.

Use [`offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetTop) if you want to work out its position as set via normal flow).

Comment: Fantastic answer - @Lenny have you tried to see if you're getting a valid result from getElementById in the first place? Could just be chasing a red herring.

Comment: Yep thanks, that was a stupid mistake I was wondering what was going on, but that explains it :)

Comment: But I am curios, is there a way to get the position even without placing the attribute?

Comment: That answers everything :) Thanks again